# How much storage are node modules taking up?

Tags: find, node.js

How could I find out how much storage all my development projects' nodeJS modules are taking up?

Maybe there is a better way, but I have all the projects within a directory. I thought maybe using `find /path/to/JS/projects -name "node_modules"` might be a good place to start. How would I constrain the depth (so as to not calculate node_mods for dependencies) and figure out the sizes of the directories' contents and add them up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To limit the calculation to the top-most `node_modules` encountered (*i.e.*, not calculate the size for dependencies, as you mention), you can run `du` and then prune:

```
find . -name node_modules -exec du -s {} \; -prune
```

This will show the size and name of all the top-most `node_modules` directories. To calculate the sum of all the sizes, feed it into *e.g.* AWK:

```
find . -name node_modules -exec du -s {} \; -prune |
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

You can feed *that* into `numfmt` to get “human-readable” values:

```
find . -name node_modules -exec du -s {} \; -prune |
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' |
numfmt --to=iec
```